# How to rebind SourceItems based on a static property that becomes dynamic?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my XAML code I've got a combo box that is bound to a static property as shown below.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DifferentKinds" 
          ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.DifferentKinds}"/>
```

And the code for the property and its source.

```csharp
public static Kind[] DifferentKinds 
  => (Kind[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Kind));

public enum Kind { WeeHee, BuuHuu }
```

I just learned that there'll be more kinds in the future. They won't be created particularly often but it's uncertain how many they might become with time. So, instead of adding new elements to the *enum*, I'll read in these from the DB.

For the simplicity of the example, let's say we read in those values every time the property is accessed. The solution becomes a private fields that is read in from the DB **before** the execution of *InitializeComponent()* starts. Then, I serve those values as a static property still, like so.

```
public MainWindow()
{
  PopulateDifferentKinds();
  InitializeComponent();
}

private static IEnumerable<Kind> _allDifferentKinds;
public static IEnumerable<Kind> AllDifferentKinds 
  => _allDifferentKinds.Where(element => element.Active);

public class Kind
{
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }

  public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}
```

1. Is this approach creating a huge problem that I miss to see?
2. Is there a better way to bind the items in the bombo box to the values from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see here is that calling the PopulateDifferentKinds method in the view's constructor will create a performance problem. While this method is running and the database is being queried, your UI is being blocked.

This could be improved using a class that loads your data on a background thread and uses a PropertyChanged event to signal that the data has been loaded:

```
public class Kind
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class AppEnumValues : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly Lazy<AppEnumValues> current
        = new Lazy<AppEnumValues>(() => new AppEnumValues(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public static AppEnumValues Current
    {
        get { return current.Value; }
    }

    public Kind[] AllDifferentKinds { get; private set; }

    public bool IsLoaded { get; private set; }

    private AppEnumValues()
    {
        Task.Run(() => this.LoadEnumValuesFromDb())
            .ContinueWith(t => this.OnAllPropertiesChanged());
    }

    protected virtual void OnAllPropertiesChanged()
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
        }
    }

    private void LoadEnumValuesFromDb()
    {
        // This simulates some latency
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Call your data service here and load the values

        var kinds = new[]
                    {
                        new Kind {Active = true, Name = "WeeHee", Value = 1},
                        new Kind {Active = true, Name = "BuuHuu", Value = 2}
                    };

        this.AllDifferentKinds = kinds;

        this.IsLoaded = true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

You could extend this with properties for each extensible "enum" you need in your application. Implementing the Singleton pattern, this would load its data in background the first time it is used. You could bind your ComboBoxes like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static wpfApplication2:AppEnumValues.Current},Path=AllDifferentKinds}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static wpfApplication2:AppEnumValues.Current},Path=IsLoaded}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

While the data is being loaded, the ComboBox would be disabled.

I would recommend looking into MVVM and Dependency Injection. This will enhance your WPF application architecture and make things like that easy: You wouldn't provide a static property or singleton, which has bad testability and extensibility, but you could use constructor injection to give the AppEnumValues provider into your View Model and then bind your view to it.

Comment: Cool. +1 for great example and substantial, spot-on explanation.